# POWER BI : Running Total without Date column and ID Column

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I have a table with just 2 columns i.e Location and Number of assessments and I want to find the Running total for the total number of assessments.

In the Image [Number of Assessments By Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8417.png) , you can see that the running total (247) is appearing but with every Location. I just want a single bar at the end displaying 247 (not 741). I have used the SUM function on the Assessment in DAX

DATA :

| Location | Assessments |
| --- | --- |
| CA | 118 |
| AT | 54 |
| MT | 33 |
| AN | 23 |
| CH | 17 |
| RM | 2 |

Comment: Please share data, the desired output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Peter - Hi, I have added the data and the desired output in the edit, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to achieve what you need, You need a derived tabular dataset which contains "Total" of all the Location.

You can create a derived table like this

```
Table =
VAR _tbl =
    UNION ( //step3-appending subTbl1 to subTbl2
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            DATATABLE ( "Local", STRING, { { "Total" } } ), //step1- creating a table that contains the total of all the locations --subTbl1
            "Value", SUMX ( t1, t1[Assessments] )
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            t1,
            "Local", t1[Location],
            "Value", CALCULATE ( SUM ( t1[Assessments] ) ) //step2-creating a table that contains the total of all the locations by location -- subTbl2
        )
    )
RETURN
    _tbl
```

Once you have that, you can plot the data points like this
[image: s1]

[image: s2]